# WebRTC: TURN server is working properly, still cannot establish peer 2 peer connection

Tags: webrtc, turn

I've run a turn server(from Coturn) on a subnet machine `192.168.1.5`, while its Internet IP is `183.xxx.xxx.xxx`, and from https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/  .
I can see the subnet ip is gathered.
[image]

The TURN startup command is:

```
turnserver -o -a -f -v --mobility -m 10 --max-bps=100000 --min-port=32355 --max-port=65535 --user=webrtc0:webrtc1234 -r demo
```

But when I open Chrome to access the WebRTC service, in console, I saw the error log:

[image]

But in FireFox, the error log is:

[image]

I'm wondering why it says `WebRTC: ICE failed, add a STUN server and see about:webrtc for more details`.

And if I visit `183.xxx.xxx.xxx:3478`, `The connection was reset`  appears :

[image]

---

Some points to notice:

1. In intranet environment, use `192.168.1.5` or `183.xxx.xxx.xxx` to access the WebRTC service is OK!

2.In Extranet environment, which is Internet environment, use `183.xxx.xxx.xxx` to access the WebRTC service failed!

The log's here:

```
1068: : session 128000000000000003: realm <demo> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
1068: : session 128000000000000003: realm <demo> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
1068: : IPv4. Local relay addr: 192.168.1.5:43040
1068: : session 128000000000000003: new, realm=<demo>, username=<webrtc0>, lifetime=600
1068: : session 128000000000000003: realm <demo> user <webrtc0>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
1068: : session 128000000000000003: refreshed, realm=<demo>, username=<webrtc0>, lifetime=0
1068: : session 128000000000000003: realm <demo> user <webrtc0>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
1069: : session 128000000000000003: usage: realm=<demo>, username=<webrtc0>, rp=4, rb=232, sp=4, sb=416
1069: : session 128000000000000003: peer usage: realm=<demo>, username=<webrtc0>, rp=0, rb=0, sp=0, sb=0
1069: : session 128000000000000003: closed (2nd stage), user <webrtc0> realm <demo> origin <>, local 192.168.1.5:3478, remote 58.101.35.211:48671, reason: allocation timeout
1069: : session 128000000000000003: delete: realm=<demo>, username=<webrtc0>
1073: : session 004000000000000003: refreshed, realm=<demo>, username=<webrtc0>, lifetime=600
1073: : session 004000000000000003: realm <demo> user <webrtc0>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
1073: : IPv4. tcp or tls connected to: 183.xxx.xxx.xxx:64128
1073: : session 001000000000000008: realm <demo> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
1073: : IPv4. Local relay addr: 192.168.1.5:48887
1073: : session 001000000000000008: new, realm=<demo>, username=<webrtc0>, lifetime=600
1073: : session 001000000000000008: realm <demo> user <webrtc0>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
1088: : session 008000000000000008: refreshed, realm=<demo>, username=<webrtc0>, lifetime=600
1088: : session 008000000000000008: realm <demo> user <webrtc0>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
1088: : IPv4. tcp or tls connected to: 183.xxx.xxx.xxx:64156
1088: : session 002000000000000008: realm <demo> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
1088: : IPv4. Local relay addr: 192.168.1.5:42791
1088: : session 002000000000000008: new, realm=<demo>, username=<webrtc0>, lifetime=600
1088: : session 002000000000000008: realm <demo> user <webrtc0>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
1089: : session 003000000000000001: realm <demo> user <webrtc0>: incoming packet message processed, error 438: Stale nonce
1089: : session 003000000000000001: refreshed, realm=<demo>, username=<webrtc0>, lifetime=600
1089: : session 003000000000000001: realm <demo> user <webrtc0>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
1104: : session 001000000000000003: refreshed, realm=<demo>, username=<webrtc0>, lifetime=600
1104: : session 001000000000000003: realm <demo> user <webrtc0>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
1104: : session 003000000000000002: realm <demo> user <webrtc0>: incoming packet message processed, error 438: Stale nonce
1104: : session 003000000000000002: refreshed, realm=<demo>, username=<webrtc0>, lifetime=600
1104: : session 003000000000000002: realm <demo> user <webrtc0>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
```

Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: What's the architecture of this system? Are the clients inside the same private network? If not, then a relayed address with a private IP won't be usable by the other party. If you're willing to debug the TURN connectivity, I wrote a troubleshooting guide that maybe can help: https://www.giacomovacca.com/2022/05/troubleshooting-turn.html

Comment: The clients are outside the private network

Comment: If the clients are outside the private network, then in order to use TURN the TURN server should provide a public relay address.  The clients exchange those relay addresses and try to use them to exchange a connection. With private relay addresses they won't be able to reach each other. Try setting `external_ip` into the coturn configuration to use the public IP address.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but now the 401 Unauthorized issue appered repeatbly. And I'm wondering if it was caused by calling `setRemoteDescription` failed because I saw `DOMException: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The remote description was null`  errof in Chrome console. Could you please give me some clues?

Comment: You should verify that coturn logs the unauthorized access, and ensure the client is using valid credentials. Then log the ICE candidate to verify there's a valid relay candidate to be exchanged.

Comment: Hi @Criwran . Is there any progress in this? I have same problem

Comment: @SulaimanTriarjo In my case, developers using the turn service incorrectly configured some parameters of the turn service in their programs. You can ask the developers if there is something wrong with them. I hope this will help you